# GET COMMAND in HTTP Request

Tags: apache-2.4, http, host

I cannot use GET command to get the web site body content only. For example:

```
[root@mrtg home]# echo -e "GET / HTTP/\r\nHost: test.com:80\r\n\r\n" | nc 192.168.1.201 80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 13:45:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 10:28:08 GMT
ETag: "6068a-10-52e786faf8f79"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 16
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

test.com-server
[root@mrtg home]#
```

If I use this command `echo -e "GET / /\r\nHost: test.com:80\r\n\r\n" | nc 192.168.1.201 80`

I can get the default host body content only. I have 3 x Virtualhost in my Apache2.4 server.

Please advise.

Comment: Just use curl...

Answer (score 2):

The GET command is

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com
```

The HTTP/1.1 is essential in order to specify the Host.

However, you should use `wget` or `curl` which are programs written for the purpose.